# Is configuration interaction able to produce degenerate ground states?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electronic-configuration, multi-reference

I am new to multi-determinant theories. What motivates me in asking this question is the following observation: Consider the Dyson orbital of a $\ce{CO2}$ molecule whose axis is parallel to the $z$ axis defined as
$$
\textrm{Dy}(x) 
  = \int \mathrm{d}x_1 \ldots \mathrm{d}x_{N-1} \, 
    (\Psi^+(x_1,\ldots,x_{N-1}))^* \, \Psi^0(x_1,\ldots,x_{N-1}, x)
$$
where $x$ is space-spin coordinate, $\Psi^0$ and $\Psi^+$ are the total wavefunctions of the neutral and cation, respectively.
Now, if you calculate the neutral and cation wave functions using Hartree-Fock method and then use them in the equation above, you will get **one** Dyson orbital with mostly $\pi$-symmetry such that its lobes are oriented in a certain direction, e.g. in $x$ direction. But there is a clear imbalance, so to speak, here, isn't there. The formula of the Dyson orbital above does not have any spatial preference and the total densities of both $\ce{CO2}$ and $\ce{CO2^+}$ are axially symmetric around the molecules' axis, so why would their Dyson orbital necessarily have a spatial preference?

I am thinking it might be due to the fact that I am using just one determinant to represent the wave functions. If this were the true reason, then would using multi-determinant methods can give me $m$-fold degenerate GS (especially for $\ce{CO2^+}$) and hence there will also be $m$ Dyson orbitals?

Comment: I have no answer for the Dyson orbital part as I couldn't find an openly available, easy to understand definition of it. So it might very well be possible, that they are ill-defined for systems with degenerate ground states, they are approximations themselves, interpretation tools, etc. That would require study of the theory. What I can tell you is, that by its definition, full CI will produce the exact expectation energy in the given basis set. In a complete basis, the wave function will also be exact. That implies that theoretically CI can reproduce a degenerate ground state. [...]

Comment: So technically you can produce two wave functions and plug them into the formalism you have written. The orbital you obtain will be as meaningless as the orbitals you have plugged in though. In the CI formalism, orbitals are not optimised, they are simply the basis. There are better techniques to describe the multi-reference character of molecules than CI; have a look at CASSCF and RASSCF. However even with those orbitals remain a mathematical approach, and since $x$ is a space-spin coordinate, you'll always end up with one Dy(x). From that I'd expect it's more an illustrative approach.

Comment: What about truncated CI, e.g. CISD, is it known to be able to produce degenerate GS?

Comment: I am not a pure chemist people either (my background is physics), so I don't have any clue how the concept of Dyson orbital is perceived within chemical community. But in atomic and molecular physics, $Dy(x)$ usually appears in the consideration of ionization process. As you may see from the equation above, that the hand-waving meaning of $Dy(x)$ is that it represents the difference between neutral and cation GS's.

Comment: By the way, I don't agree that Dyson orbital is meaningless as it is unique, unlike ordinary orbitals. To see why this is so, imagine when one hypothetically has the exact wavefunctions for neutral and cation. The equation above clearly guarantees that Dyson orbital so calculated will be unique.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン It is better not to interpret Dyson orbitals in the same way like molecular  orbitals that form a basis set. Dyson orbitals normally occur when modeling photo-ionization processes. It can be interpreted as describing an orbital from which an electron is emitted upon ionization. The overlap of the Dyson orbital with scattering states contributes to the ionization probability of a photo-ionization process. I don't know if this is the background here but that is one application where Dyson orbitals are used. The calculation of the Dyson orbital happens afterwards, not during the CI.

Comment: @HansWurst, exactly. In my research, I will come to a point where I need to be able to compute the Dyson orbital, which is then to be plugged into a sort of overlap integral. The integral is roughly an overlap between Dyson orbital with a function that is somehow related to scattering states. The ionization probability is then proportional to this overlap integral.